# Hexdigest from passing parameter

Tags: python

I wanted to create a function that could hash a string using sha.
Here's my code:

```
def hashNow(number,string):
       for i in range (number):
            hashH = int(hashlib.sha1(string.hexdigest(),16)
            print hashH #debug purpose
            indexing = hashH % len(arrays)
            arrays[indexing] = 1
```

When I compile this code, it prints `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` pointing at the `print hashH`. Based on my experience, invalid syntax error usually is an error carrier from the previous line.

My question: am I implementing the hexdigest incorrectly? Why `string.hexdigest()` cause a syntax error?

Comment: You are missing a closing `)` on the `hashH = ..` line.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here at all; `str` objects do not have a `hexdigest` method. If you don't want the hex digest (you are decoding it again as integer), why not just use the `.digest()` method and get the bytes directly?

Comment: the [`hexdigest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest) call must be done to the result of `hashlib.sha1()`: `hashlib.sha1(string).hexdigest()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hey Martjin, I'm trying to pass any string like `bacon` or `coffee` into the `hashNow` function. Then I want this function to convert it to hex like `7FBIFM8FF.... (maybe)` and then mod it to a number. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

One syntax error is that there is missing a closing bracket of the int()-call. Another error is, that sha1() returns an object what can't be converted to int (I'm trying it in python 2.7). By the way, sha-1 isn't really safe, sha-2 and sha-3 are better.

Comment: I used sha-1 because that's what available in hashlib options and I heard that it's better than md5. Am I wrong?

Comment: ok, if the other hash-functions aren't supported it's reasonable to use sha-1